# webpack failed to compile. Kendo Angular ui

Tags: kendo-ui, webpack, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I just enhanced my app with kendo's DialogModule, and now webpacks fails to compie, due to this error:

```
ERROR in /Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/intl.service.d.ts (1,117): Cannot find module '@telerik/kendo-intl'.

ERROR in /Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/cldr-intl.service.d.ts (1,117): Cannot find module '@telerik/kendo-intl'.

ERROR in /Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/date.pipe.d.ts (3,35): Cannot find module '@telerik/kendo-intl'.

ERROR in /Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/number.pipe.d.ts (3,37): Cannot find module '@telerik/kendo-intl'.

ERROR in /Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/intl-members.d.ts (1,117): Cannot find module '@telerik/kendo-intl'.

ERROR in ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/intl-members.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@telerik/kendo-intl' in '/Users/marco/ants-web-v2/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es'
 @ ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/intl-members.js 1:0-44
 @ ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/es/main.js
 @ ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/grid.module.js
 @ ./~/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/es/main.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

this is my package.json content:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^1.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^1.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^1.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.37.5",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  }
```

I'm aware i'm using angular4, so far it never caused any problem

Comment: Could you try with Angular 4.1.x? There was a known issue in Angular 4.2, which was producing a not very valid ng factories. If the issue still persists, could you give more details? Webpack configuration and etc. A runnable plunkr or cli generated project will be of a great help too.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a setup of Angular 4.2.6 and Kendo UI. Try the following dependencies in your package.json. It works for me.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "1.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "1.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "1.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "1.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.38.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.13"
  }
```

I hope the current versions of the Kendo UI dialog and intl package fix your issue.

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.2.1"
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "1.0.4"
```

Update: Angular 4.3.0 is out - you may try this version instead of 4.2.6